# Configure Heroku app with only scheduled jobs?

Tags: heroku, procfile

I want to spin up a Heroku instance that only runs a few jobs scheduled with the Heroku Scheduler add-on.  I don't want any processes to start on deploy.  Should I configure a dummy process, add an empty Procfile, omit the Procfile, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

An empty Procfile works.  Still need to try omitting the Procfile.

Comment: Be aware that using an empty Procfile effectively prevents you from having HTTP traffic. Heroku gives you about one free dyno per month (750h, which is a bit more, leaving you time for short-lived tasks).